# How to set layer hierarchy?

Tags: outliner

I need a matching hierarchy of shape keys to match a saved file form another app. I need the shape keys of the head first, then the tongue, then teeth, etc.

Is there a procedure to bump up or down a layer in the outliner? Already alphabetical order is turned off to see the actual order.

The only way I know is the long way, to unparent and then reparent each layer from the armature in the desired order one at a time.

But if there was a shorter way of doing this that would be a time saver, that is what I wish I knew.

Comment: Do you have to match the exact name of the shape keys as well, or are you only interested in the order?

Comment: Both, but the name matching is not the unknown part of my task.